# Select only rows with certain critiera then output data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So im developing a web page with the following sql query:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fotf_images` WHERE `image_fotfnum` = '$Fivedigits'");
```

now, $fivedigits is a $_POST from a previous forms input data. So basically the form parses the mysql db for rows that contain ONLY $Fivedigits in a specific column. What i want to do, is output EVERY row that has these criteria. So far i used the following:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
print_r($row);  
}
```

this only seems to output the first row, when i know as a fact there are exactly 2 rows that contain the criteria. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Your code should work as long as your data are correct. You can use `mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)` instead, if you like. Are you sure the column` image_fotfnum` matches *exactly* $Fivedigits in both rows?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all rows whose image_fotfnum contains  $fivedigits content? If so, just use `\`image_fotfnum\` LIKE '%$fivedigits%'`

Comment: The code looks fine, so maybe the criteria are wrong after all, or they don't work how you think they work. If there are two rows that contain that *exact* value in `image_fotnum`, then you should see both of them. Only recommendation is to rename `$sql` to `$results` or something. The variable contains a query result resource, rather than the SQL to get it, so it's confusing (but not wrong).

Comment: Not the only.. I also recommend to move to `PDO` or maybe `mysqli`. :)

Comment: And be wary of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: see thats the problem. the code is correct, but its ONLY outputting ONE row. Both columns have the same EXACT data. not sure whats up?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
    Select * from fotf_images 
where Concat(image_fotfnum, '', field2, '', fieldn) 
like concat('%','",$Fivedigits,"','%')
```

since its not only numeric you may need to use LOWER or UPPER case while comparing. This will help you search in every mentioned feilds of fotf_images table